# Limit of a recurrent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let a>2 .

> $\phi_0=a$ and $\phi=a- \frac{1}{\phi}$
>
> I would like to determine the series limit and used ratio test for the convergence but I got lost.

Any help please?

Comment: Do you mean $\phi_{n+1}=a-\frac{1}{\phi_{n}}$

Comment: you are right,  but I wrote the suite as  n---> infinity .

Answer (score 1):

For $a > 2$, the map $x \mapsto a - \frac1x$ has two fixed points:
$$b = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}\quad\text{ and }\quad b^{-1} = \frac{a - \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}$$

Instead of studying sequence $\phi_n$ directly, one can study auxiliary sequence of the form $\psi_n = f(\phi_n)$ where $f(\phi)$ are rational function in $\phi$.
Sometimes, for suitable choice of $f(\phi)$, the recurrence relation of $\psi_n$ can be significantly simpler.

In this case, consider the auxiliary sequence $\psi_n = \frac{\phi_n - b}{1 - b\phi_n}$. It satisfies

$$\psi_{n+1} 
=\frac{\left(b + \frac1b - \frac1{\phi_n}\right) - b}{1 - b\left(b + \frac1b - \frac1{\phi_n}\right)}
= \frac1{b^2}\frac{\phi_n - b}{1 - b\phi_n}
= \frac1{b^2}\psi_n
$$ 
Solving it give us $\displaystyle\;\psi_n = \frac{1}{b^{2(n-1)}}\psi_1$ for 
generic $n$. Since $b > 1$, we obtain

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \psi_n = 0\quad\implies\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} \phi_n 
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\psi_n + b}{1 + b\psi_n} = \frac{0+b}{1+b\cdot 0} = b$$

**Update**

For an alternative evaluation of the limit without above transform, one can look at the differences $\phi_n - b$. We have

$$\phi_{n+1} - b = \left(b + \frac1b - \frac1{\phi_n}\right) - b = \frac{\phi_n - b}{b\phi_n}$$
Notice when $\phi_n > b$, RHS and hence LHS is positive. Furthermore,
$$0 < \phi_{n+1} - b < \frac{\phi_n - b}{b^2}\tag{*1}$$
Since $\phi_0 = a = b + \frac1b > b$, we can use induction to conclude $(*1)$ is true for all $n \ge 0$.
From this, we can deduce
$$0 < \phi_n - b < \frac{\phi_0 - b}{b^{2n}} = \frac{1}{b^{2n+1}}, \quad\text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Taking limsup and liminf from both sides, we obtain:

$$0 \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \phi_n - b \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \phi_n - b \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{b^{2n+1}} = 0$$

Since both limsup and liminf of $\phi_n - b$ exists and equals to $0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi_n$ exists and equals to $b$.

Comment: I did to get how the auxiliary sequence expression was elaborated at first ?

Comment: @SAM.Am By experience. There are quite a few non-linear recurrence relations which can be attached by this method. For example, the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) of computing square roots $x_{n+1} = \frac12\left(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n}\right)$ If you let $y_n = \frac{x_n - \sqrt{a}}{x_n + \sqrt{a}}$, then $y_n$ satisfies a simpler relation: $y_{n+1} = y_n^2$. The basic idea is when you use a rational transform to map the fixed points to $0$ and $\infty$, the errors becomes more "symmetric" and hence easier to bound.

Comment: The limit is correct. since I managed to demonstrate that. $\phi_n \geq b ( the root) $.    This kind of mapping  is really impressing as I've never used it before.  Nonetheless may I have a simpler limit calculation since your solution is beyond my actual competencies. 

At the origin  I started with this series. 

Let a>2 .

> $\phi=a- \frac{1}{a- \frac{1}{a-\frac{1}{a-\frac{1}{....}}}}$

>$\phi_0=a$ and $\phi_{n+1}=a-\frac{1}{\phi_n}$